# Using spring-retry @EnableRetry with spring-batch causes unexpected proxy

Tags: spring-batch, aop, spring-aop, spring-retry

I am trying to make use of the spring-retry library in my batch job and on adding the `@EnableRetry` annotation to my `@Configuration` as documentation suggests my application is now failing because it appears a spring-batch library bean which is being `@Autowired` is being proxied.

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableRetry
@Import({SpringBatchConfiguration.class, School192ClientConfiguration.class })
public class SchoolJobConfiguration { .. }
```

Exception:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'jobRegistry' is expected to be of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.JobRegistry' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy130'

I have added the following to a separate class:

```
@Retryable(value = School192ClientException.class, maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 2000))
@Override
protected void doReadPage() {
```

My question is why is this bean (`jobRegistry`) being proxied? (*I don't have much experience with AOP*).

I am using `spring-boot` version `1.5.3.RELEASE`.

Comment: Where is that bean configured?

Comment: Spring Boot is auto configuring that for me. Upgrading my version of spring-retry to 1.1.5.RELEASE and spring-boot to 1.5.7.RELEASE seems to rid me of the problem. (though I am no better off understanding the original cause)

Comment: The likely problem was the combination of using java proxies and cglib proxies which is why I was asking where it was configured.

Comment: I am using spring boot and the spring boot batch starter, which is wiring all that for me. I couldn’t see any annotations which I would expect to make that class a candidate for proxying but maybe thats my lack of understanding?

Comment: how looks SpringBatchConfiguration class?